# how to group objects in reportlab, so that they stay together across new pages

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm generating some pdf files using reportlab. I have a certain section that is repeated. It contains of a header and a table:

```
            Story.append(Paragraph(header_string, styleH))
            Story.append(table)
```

How can I group the paragraph with the table (in latex I would put them into the same environment) so that in case of a page brake, the paragraph and table stay together? Currently the paragraph sometimes floats at the end of one page and the table starts on top of the next page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is the solution that I found going through the reportlab source code:

```
paragraph = Paragraph(header_string, styleH)
paragraph.keepWithNext = True
Story.append(paragraph)
Story.append(table)
```

Comment: I like using `story[-1].keepWithNext = True` as it makes code shorter and cleaner and can be easily added and removed without having to change the variable name.  It's useful for keeping items in loops together because you can set `story[-1].keepWithNext = True` in the loop and then `story[-1].keepWithNext = False` after the loop to disconnect the stuff added in the loop from whatever is added next.

Comment: @jenniwren can you expand on that a little bit? Really interested in what flowable would be at the -1 index. Could help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: The -1 index refers to the last item in the list.  In this case, it is the last flowable appended to the story.

Answer (score 14):

You can try to put them together in a `KeepTogether` flowable, like so:

```
Story.append(KeepTogether([Paragraph(header_string, styleH), table])
```

However be aware that, last I checked, the implementation was not perfect and would still split up items too frequently.  I know it does a good job of keeping a single flowable together that would otherwise split, like if you were to say:

```
Story.append(KeepTogether(Paragraph(header_string, styleH))
```

then that paragraph would not get split unless it was impossible for it not to be.

If `KeepTogether` doesn't work for you, I'd suggest creating a custom `Flowable` with your paragraph and table inside it and then during layout make sure your custom `Flowable` subclass does not allow itself to be split up.

Answer (score 5):

Using a ParagraphStyle might actually be better so i figured i'd add it to this super old answer.

Found this in their changelog after seeing @memyself's answer.

```
  * `KeepWithNext` improved:
    Paragraph styles have long had an attribute keepWithNext, but this was 
    buggy when set to True. We believe this is fixed now. keepWithNext is important 
    for widows and orphans control; you typically set it to True on headings, to 
    ensure at least one paragraph appears after the heading and that you don't get 
    headings alone at the bottom of a column.
```

```py
header = ParagraphStyle(name='Heading1', parent=normal, fontSize=14, leading=19,
                        spaceAfter=6, keepWithNext=1)
```

Comment: Excellent choice/solution. I love the fact that you add this to Styling, as this type of layout control is in fact styling. Imho very Pythonic ;-)