# Python Reportlab Paragraph not crossing over next page

Tags: python, pdf, python-2.7, reportlab, platypus

Currently I am trying to create `PDF documents` with `reportlab` in python. On each page of my PDF , it will have multiple questions like this:

[image]

After looking around, i tried to achieve this format by using `Platypus SimpleDocTemplate` and `Platypus Paragraph`. Like this (FYI - this is not the complete code but i think this will give you a rough idea)

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('myfile.pdf')
Story = [Spacer(1,1.65*inch)]
style = styles['Normal']

quetsionno = Paragraph('Questoin no goes here',style)
myquestion = Paragraph('my question goes here',style)
myanswer1 = Paragraph('my answer1 goes here',style)
myanswer2 = Paragraph('my answer2 goes here',style)
myanswer3 = Paragraph('my answer3 goes here',style)

Story.append(quetsionno)     
Story.append(myquestion)
Story.append(myanswer1)
Story.append(myanswer2)
Story.append(myanswer3)
Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))

doc.build(Story)
```

It create the questions the way i want, but whenever the question reach toward the end of a page, it splits the question and it's answers. Like this:

[image]

I don't want that to happen, so according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797536/how-to-group-objects-in-reportlab-so-that-they-stay-together-across-new-pages), I tried using `paragraph.keepWithNext = True` but it doesn't make any difference.

Is there any way to keep my question+answers together in the same page (if there's not enough space)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your questions and answers together in a `KeepTogether` instance:

```
question = Paragraph('What color is the sky?', style)
answer1 = Paragraph('Red', style)
answer2 = Paragraph('Green', style)
answer3 = Paragraph('Blue', style)

Story.append(KeepTogether([question, answer1, answer2, answer3]))
```

ReportLab will try to keep everything in the list on the same page.

You can import the function with

`from reportlab.platypus import KeepTogether`

Comment: `KeepTogether` is one of the answers in the link i have provided in my question. When i use it, i always get this error message `NameError: global name 'KeepTogether' is not defined`

Comment: @ChrisAung You have to import it first at the top of your script, like this: `from reportlab.platypus import KeepTogether`